# Ubuntu server remote ssh troubles

Tags: server, ssh

I have a following problem:
I can't connect to a freshly deployed ubuntu-server 11.10 through SSH from a remote host.
Error: Connection timeout.

Troubleshooting so far:

1. Connect locally - Connecting through SSH on a local network works like a charm.
2. Check the router - There are no rules that can impact ssh traffic.
3. Check the distro - If I launch a Ubuntu-desktop liveCD on the same machine - everything works as it should.

So, the distro's default configuration seems to be the culprit.

Configuration details:
- OpenSSH has been installed through selecting a role during the installation.
- Other than that everything is configured by default.

Verbose SSH output:
Here's the output, everything freezes after trying to estabilish a connection (Port 2102 is forwarded to port 22 on the server):

```
ssh -vvv -p 2102 myhost
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myhost [hostip] port 2102.
debug1: connect to address hostip port 2102: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host myhost port 2102: Operation timed out
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Well, the distro's "default configuration" is "no open ports by default", so openssh-server does not get installed automatically.  But once you install it, there should be no problems connecting.  Basically, I'm saying I don't know.  (To me step 2 -- router configuration -- seems most likely, but in that case I can't explain why you can connect to a livecd running on the same machine.  More details could be useful.)

Comment: like @MariusGedminas says -"... More details could b useful."

Comment: I'm willing to provide them. What details do you require?

Comment: Well, first, on the server, can you do `netstat -tnlvp|grep :22' and put the output in your question?  That will tell us on what interface the ssh server is listening (ought to be 0.0.0.0, i.e. all of them).

Comment: Second, is there a firewall configured on the server itself?  `sudo iptables -L INPUT` will tell you what the rules are.  If you see a REJECT or DENY anywhere, that could be a Clue.

Comment: Third (though most important), what's the error you get when you try to connect?

Comment: Netstat gives 0.0.0.0, as it should. Concerning the error - I get a connection timeout. Iptables have no DENY rules, everything is allowed.

Comment: Run `ssh -vvv nameofhost`, post the output, tell us if the output pauses for a noticeable time at any point.

Comment: @Gilles I added the SSH verbose output per your request.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=92803 prob Solved

Comment: google "debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0" u will find the results

Comment: I do not thing that the line itself is connected to the issue, but the search results gave me some ideas. I think I fixed the issue, at least partially...

Answer (score 1):

I think my router screws up DNS retranslation.
Following options in the sshd_config fixed the issue, at least partially:

```
UseDNS no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Comment: I'm surprised that you saw a timeout and not merely a delay of a few seconds, but switching these options off is indeed a good idea most of the time.